# Prometheus Email Notification

Tags: email, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a `Prometheus` `Operator` running on `Kubernetes` that works and i can monitor my resources and cluster whit it. But i don't receive email notification with alerts firing. What should i do to get email ?

```
pod/alertmanager-kube-prometheus-0                         2/2     Running   0          72m
pod/kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state-86b466d978-sp24r   2/2     Running   0          161m
pod/kube-prometheus-exporter-node-2zjc6                    1/1     Running   0          162m
pod/kube-prometheus-exporter-node-gwxlg                    1/1     Running   0          162m
pod/kube-prometheus-exporter-node-ngc5p                    1/1     Running   0          162m
pod/kube-prometheus-exporter-node-vcrw4                    1/1     Running   0          162m
pod/kube-prometheus-grafana-6c4dffd84d-mfws7               2/2     Running   0          162m
pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-0                           3/3     Running   1          162m
pod/prometheus-operator-545b59ffc9-tpqs5                   1/1     Running   0          163m

NAME                                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/alertmanager-operated                 ClusterIP   None             <none>        9093/TCP,6783/TCP   162m
service/kube-prometheus                       NodePort    10.106.17.176    <none>        9090:31984/TCP      162m
service/kube-prometheus-alertmanager          NodePort    10.105.17.59     <none>        9093:30365/TCP      162m
service/kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state   ClusterIP   10.105.149.175   <none>        80/TCP              162m
service/kube-prometheus-exporter-node         ClusterIP   10.111.234.174   <none>        9100/TCP            162m
service/kube-prometheus-grafana               ClusterIP   10.106.183.201   <none>        80/TCP              162m
service/prometheus-operated                   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9090/TCP            162m

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/kube-prometheus-exporter-node   4         4         4       4            4           <none>          162m

NAME                                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state   1/1     1            1           162m
deployment.apps/kube-prometheus-grafana               1/1     1            1           162m
deployment.apps/prometheus-operator                   1/1     1            1           163m

NAME                                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state-5858d86974   0         0         0       162m
replicaset.apps/kube-prometheus-exporter-kube-state-86b466d978   1         1         1       161m
replicaset.apps/kube-prometheus-grafana-6c4dffd84d               1         1         1       162m
replicaset.apps/prometheus-operator-545b59ffc9                   1         1         1       163m

NAME                                            READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/alertmanager-kube-prometheus   1/1     162m
statefulset.apps/prometheus-kube-prometheus     1/1     162m
```

And i put my `AlertManager.yaml` configure in secret

`kubectl edit secret alertmanager-kube-prometheus  -n monitoring`

```
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  alertmanager.yaml: Z2xvYmFsOgogIHNtdHBfc21hcnRob3N0OiAnc210cC5nbWFpbC5jb206NTg3JwogIHNtdHBfZnJvbTogJ3pvay5jbzIyMkBnbWFpbC5jb20nCiAgc210cF9hdXRoX3VzZXJuYW1lOiAnem9rLmNvMjIyQGdtYWlsLmNvbScKICBzbXRwX2F1dGhfcGFzc3dvcmQ6ICdIaWZ0MjIyJwoKdGVtcGxhdGVzOiAKLSAnL2V0Yy9hbGVydG1hbmFnZXIvdGVtcGxhdGUvKi50bXBsJwoKCnJvdXRlOgogIAogIGdyb3VwX2J5OiBbJ2FsZXJ0bmFtZScsICdjbHVzdGVyJywgJ3NlcnZpY2UnICwgJ3NldmVyaXR5J10KCiAgZ3JvdXBfd2FpdDogMzBzCgogIGdyb3VwX2ludGVydmFsOiA1bQoKICByZXBlYXRfaW50ZXJ2YWw6
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-04-14T07:00:50Z"
  labels:
    alertmanager: kube-prometheus
    app: alertmanager
    chart: alertmanager-0.1.7
    heritage: Tiller
    release: kube-prometheus
  name: alertmanager-kube-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "598489"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/secrets/alertmanager-kube-prometheus
  uid: 099ab6d0-ffff-11e9-9f0d-5254001850dc
type: Opaque
```

And my `AlertManager.yaml` looks like this:

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
  smtp_from: 'zok@gmail.com'
  smtp_auth_username: 'zok@gmail.com'
  smtp_auth_password: 'xxxxxx'

templates: 
- '/etc/alertmanager/template/*.tmpl'


route:

  group_by: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service' , 'severity']

  group_wait: 30s

  group_interval: 5m

  repeat_interval: 1h 

  receiver: email-me

  routes:
  - match_re:
      service: ^(foo1|foo2|baz)$
    receiver: email-me
    routes:
    - match:
        severity: critical
      receiver: email-me
    - match:
        service: files
      receiver: email-me

    - match:
        severity: warning
      receiver: email-me

  - match:
      service: database
    receiver: email-me

    group_by: [alertname, cluster, database]
    routes:
    - match:
        owner: team-X
      receiver: email-me
      continue: true

    - match:
        severity: warning
      receiver: email-me 

    - match:
        severity: front-critical
      receiver: email-me   


receivers:
- name: 'email-me'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'meisam@gmail.com'

- name: 'team-Y-mails'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'meisam@gmail.com
```

My Alerting list in `Prometheus` dashboard :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWA9L.jpg

Comment: Take a look at Alertmanager logs (`kubectl logs alertmanager-kube-prometheus-0 alertmanager`). Also, take a look at Alertmanager UI to see if the alerts were received. _Oooh, looks like you posted real sensitive info here...Consider [editing out the sensitive info from your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/353042), and changing your passwords..._

Comment: Just to be sure, did you authorized insecure applications in you gmail control panel ?

Comment: Also, you may be miising a `smtp_require_tls: true` parameter